# The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following Repository method:-

```
public AccountDefinition GetCustomer2(int id)
{
    var c = entities.AccountDefinitions
            .Where(p=>p.ORG_ID==id)
            .Include(a => a.SDOrganization)
            .Include(a2 => a2.SiteDefinitions)
            .Include(a3 => a3.SDOrganization.AaaPostalAddresses)
            .Include(a4 => a4.SiteDefinitions.SelectMany
                              (a5 => a5.DepartmentDefinitions.SelectMany
                                    (a6 => a6.SDUsers.Select
                                          (a7 => a7.AaaUser))))
                                                   .SingleOrDefault();

    return c;
}
```

The the following action method which calls the above method:-

```
public ActionResult Details2(int id = 0)
{
    AccountDefinition cd = repository.GetCustomer2(id);
    return View("copy",cd);
}
```

but when i navigate to the Action Method , i get the following error on the repository class:-

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type.  Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties.

So what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you may want to do something like

```
public AccountDefinition GetCustomer2(int id)
        {

            var c = entities.AccountDefinitions.Where(p=>p.ORG_ID==id)
                .Include(a => a.SDOrganization)
                .Include(a2 => a2.SiteDefinitions)
                .Include(a3 => a3.SDOrganization.AaaPostalAddresses)
                .Include(a4 => a4.SiteDefinitions.Select(a5 => a5.DepartmentDefinitions.Select(a6 => a6.SDUsers.Select(a7 => a7.AaaUser))));

            return c;
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the SDOrganization does not have a .Select. And if i write your code i will get the following error:-""Error 2 'TMS.Models.SDOrganization' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'TMS.Models.SDOrganization' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?""

Comment: I see, then the problem is probably SelectMany, change SelectMany to Select instead.

Comment: i was stuck on some other problem but ur answer pointed me in right direction

Comment: @AtulChaudhary Me too, but this solution helped. I wanted to include a virtual collection of properties in a root property.
This is my resulting query: return this.Entities.Where(x => x.Id == id)
                .Include(x => x.QuestionSets).AsNoTracking()
                .Include(x => x.ProductTradeTypeMAPs).AsNoTracking()
                .Include(x => x.ProductTradeTypeMAPs.Select(y => y.TradeType)).AsNoTracking()
                .SingleOrDefault();