# Loading all the children entities with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have a data model like this

[image: Data Model]

I would like to load all the related entities from a Reconciliation into a Reconciliation object.

For now the only way I could find to load all the related entites to a single Recon is in multiple Lists. **But I want to load every related entities in a `Reconciliation` object.** If possible in an elegant way.

```
Reconciliation recon = db.Reconciliations
  .Where(r => r.ReconNum == 382485).First();

List<ReconciliationDetail> reconDetails = recon.ReconciliationDetails.ToList();
List<JrnlEntryDetail> jrnlDetails = reconDetails.Select(r => r.JrnlEntryDetail).ToList();
List<JrnlEntry> jrnl = jrnlDetails.Select(j => j.JrnlEntry).ToList();

List<ARInvoice> invoices = jrnl.SelectMany(j => j.ARInvoices).ToList();
List<ARInvoiceDetail> invoicesDetail = invoices
  .SelectMany(i => i.ARInvoiceDetails).ToList();

List<ARCredMemo> credmemos = jrnl.SelectMany(j => j.ARCredMemoes).ToList();
List<ARCredMemoDetail> credmemosDetail = credmemos
  .SelectMany(c => c.ARCredMemoDetails).ToList();

List<IncomingPay> incomingPays = jrnl.SelectMany(j => j.IncomingPays).ToList();
List<IncomingPayDetail> incomingPaysDetail = incomingPays
  .SelectMany(i => i.IncomingPayDetails).ToList();

// ... and so on for outgoing pays, AP Invoices AP Cred Memo ...etc
```

I have also tried to load it with `Include` and `Select` but I get this exception :

*The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.*

And I don't get how I could load every childs of JrnlEntry using `Include` and `Select`

```
Reconciliation recon = db.Reconciliations
  .Where(r => r.ReconNum == 382485)
  .Include(r => r.ReconciliationDetails
    .Select(d => d.JrnlEntryDetail)
    .Select(jd => jd.JrnlEntry)
    .SelectMany(j => j.ARInvoices).SelectMany(i => i.ARInvoiceDetails))
```

**Edit**

Managed to do it this way too but it's not very beautiful :

```
Reconciliation recon = db.Reconciliations
.Where(r => r.ReconNum == 382485)
  .Include(r => r.ReconciliationDetails.Select(rd => rd.JrnlEntryDetail)
    .Select(jd => jd.JrnlEntry).Select(j => j.ARInvoices.Select(i => i.ARInvoiceDetails)))
  .Include(r => r.ReconciliationDetails.Select(rd => rd.JrnlEntryDetail)
    .Select(jd => jd.JrnlEntry).Select(j => j.ARCredMemoes.Select(c => c.ARCredMemoDetails)))
  .Include(r => r.ReconciliationDetails.Select(rd => rd.JrnlEntryDetail)
    .Select(jd => jd.JrnlEntry).Select(j => j.IncomingPays.Select(i => i.IncomingPayDetails)))
  .Include(r => r.ReconciliationDetails.Select(rd => rd.JrnlEntryDetail)
    .Select(jd => jd.JrnlEntry).Select(j => j.OutgoingPays.Select(o => o.OutgoingPayDetails)))
  .Include(r => r.ReconciliationDetails.Select(rd => rd.JrnlEntryDetail)
    .Select(jd => jd.JrnlEntry).Select(j => j.APInvoices.Select(o => o.APInvoiceDetails)))
  .Include(r => r.ReconciliationDetails.Select(rd => rd.JrnlEntryDetail)
    .Select(jd => jd.JrnlEntry).Select(j => j.APCredMemoes.Select(o => o.APCredMemoDetails)))
  .Include(r => r.ReconciliationDetails.Select(rd => rd.JrnlEntryDetail)
    .Select(jd => jd.JrnlEntry).Select(j => j.JrnlEntryDetails))
```

Comment: Please check this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596315/the-include-path-expression-must-refer-to-a-navigation-property-defined-on-the-t

Comment: Your solution under **Edit** seems to be the correct way of expressing what you want using `.Include()`. However, do check what SQL is actually generated (by doing, say, `Debug.WriteLine(recon.ToString())`). If you want to avoid multiple db calls, but you want more efficient SQL, try the approach described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ691402.aspx. This would probably be easier to read and *much* more efficient.

Answer (score 28):

There are two ways to perform **[Eager Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)** in Entity Framework:

- [ObjectQuery.Include Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Explicit loading using either [DbEntityEntry.Collection Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.collection%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) or [DbEntityEntry.Reference Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.reference%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) along with their respective Load methods

There are also manners to write [Raw SQL Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) against database:

- [DbSet.SqlQuery Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) deals with entities
- [Database.SqlQuery Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) deals with arbitrary types
- [Database.ExecuteSqlCommand Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) for arbitrary DDL/DML

For the case, when you're attempting to load nearly entire database, it would be good idea to execute dedicated store procedure against it.

Comment: I have a entity with 15 references and 3 collections. I could not find a way to load all of them without explicitly mentioning them with Include(). Is there a smart way of loading references and collections?

Answer (score 8):

Try with just `.Include(r => r.ReconciliationDetails)` initially.  Then add the `.Select()` statements one-by-one.  At what point does the exception reappear?  The `.SelectMany()` call looks a bit suspicious to me!

A second question that might help identify the problem...  After you run the code that contains all the `ToList()` calls, is your `recon` entity complete?  i.e. are all its navigation properties populated?  This *should* be the case because of the automatic 'fixup' behavior of Entity Framework.

With EF, sometimes it is more efficient to load a complex object graph with several calls rather than chained `Include()` calls.  Check the generated SQL and see what is most efficient in your case.

Comment: To your second question, yes after I run the code that contains the to list, recon entity is complete !

Comment: Great. Otherwise it would have suggested a problem with your model. So try following the suggestion from @MotomotoPink to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596315/the-include-path-expression-must-refer-to-a-navigation-property-defined-on-the-t.  The solution there was to avoid `SelectMany()`.

Comment: `Try with just .Include(r => r.ReconciliationDetails) initially. Then add the .Select() statements one-by-one` -> When I get to JrnlEntry like this `.Include(r => r.ReconciliationDetails.Select(rd => rd.JrnlEntryDetail).Select(jd => jd.JrnlEntry).Select(CAN ADD ONLY ONE HERE BUT WILL REMAIN 5 TO ADD))` I can add one more Entity but not the six ones that are directly related to JrnlEntry

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's to late but could you benefit from structuring your code such as

```
var acctName = "someName";

var detailList =  _repository.Include(e => e.JrnlEntryDetail).Filter(c => c.JrnlEntryDetail.Any(e => e.AcctName == acctName)).Get().ToList();
```